# What are some options that exist for osx like MacRuby, but using javascript?

Tags: javascript, macos, tidesdk

Just wondering what are some of the options out there people know of.

curious what other people use.

Comment: question is about writing native apps in js, much in the way you can write them in ruby using macruby. wondering what people use for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

k. just came across another: 
JSCocoa http://inexdo.com/JSCocoa

and

TideSDK: http://tidesdk.org